# htaccess rewrite rules with different paths

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have written a rule to redirect everything after slash to `index.php?section=site`. This rule works fine:

```
RewriteRule (.*)(\/)? index.php?section=site
```

If the uri is `/cms/....` I want to redirect it to `index.php?section=cms`. The problem is the first rule says everything going to `index.php?section=site` so how I can to avoid that if the start of the url is cms ?

**I tried this :**

```
RewriteRule (.*)(\/)? index.php?section=site
RewriteRule cms\/(.*) index.php?section=cms [L]
```

**For example :**

1. url like : domain.com/login , belongs to index.php?section=site
2. url like : domain.com/cms/login , belongs to index.php?section=cms

Comment: reverse the order of the rewrite rules. so that the CMS rule is first.

Comment: Try:
`RewriteRule cms/(.*) index.php?section=cms [L] 
RewriteRule (.*)(\/)? index.php?section=site`

Answer (score 1):

If this is your only rule and your goal is to use `index.php` as a [Front-end Controller](http://onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2004/07/08/front_controller.html), I recommend using [`FallbackResource`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource) and parsing/routing the request with PHP.

```
FallbackResource /index.php
```

In the end, it avoids the overhead and complexity of `mod_rewrite` and arguably provides greater flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

I found easy solution cuz everything I tried with htaccess didnt worked.

.htaccess file :

```
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
```

index file :

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$ex = explode("/",$uri);
switch($ex[2])
{
    case "cms":
        // cms dispatch here
    break;

    default:
       // site dispatch here
    break;

}
```

Thanks anyway :)